# Google Chrome Font Rendering

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, font-face, webfonts

I am encountering an issue with basic font rendering in Google Chrome Canary. I am embedding the typeface "Proxima Nova" onto a site I am developing via Typekit. Currently this is only hosted locally, so I will have to do my best to show the issue through screenshots and code samples.

Long story short, any time I use any webfont, in Google Chrome Canary (currently 40.0.2202.3), my fonts are rendering way too heavy. Briefly, for less than a second after page load, the font is rendered at the correct thickness and then it will fatten up within a second of the browser load. I have tried disabling all plugins and the issue still exists. When I disable CSS on the page, it renders consistently with other browsers (as one would expect). Fonts render properly in Chrome 38 & 39, as well as all other major browsers. I have tested in both Windows and Mac OS with the same results. I created a codepen to demo this, which has the exact HTML and CSS that is in place on the site: http://codepen.io/idealbrandon/pen/EGlDa

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <aside class="masthead">
    <h1 class="h2">Advancing Drainage through J-DRain, Grid-Guard and TurfCore.</h1>
    <p class="h3">Sed consequat pretium dictum. Viva mus blandit, turpis sed es ultrices sollicitudin, risus seme finibus ipsum, in faucibus diam dolor vel felis.</p>
  </aside>
  <main>
    This is the main section
  </main>
</div>
```

**SASS/SCSS**

```
// Standard Measurements
$max-width:             102.4rem;
$base-font:             1.4rem;
$baseline:              $base-font*1.5;

// Media Queries
$small-up:               "only screen and (min-width: 320px)";
$small-up2:              "only screen and (min-width: 450px)";
$medium-up:              "only screen and (min-width: 600px)";
$large-up:               "only screen and (min-width: 1050px)";

// Font Declerations
$font-body:             'proxima-nova', sans-serif;
$font-icon:             'jdr';

// Color
$black:                 #000000;
$white:                 #FFFFFF;
$gray:                  #323132;
$gray-light:            #939597;
$blue:                  #0970B8;
$green:                 #38B449;

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font: {
    family: $font-body;
    size: 1.4rem;
  }
  color: $gray;
  background-color: $white;
  line-height: $baseline;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  //text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: $baseline;

  &.align-left {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 $baseline $baseline 0;
  }

  &.align-right {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 $baseline $baseline;
  }
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

// Mini Reset
//// Setting type to baseline grid
p,
ul,
ol,
dl {
  margin-bottom: $baseline;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: $font-body;
  line-height: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: $baseline;
}

h1,
.h1 {
  font-size: 3.2rem;
  line-height: 3.6rem;

  @media #{$medium-up} {
    font-size: 3.6rem;
    line-height: 4.0rem;
  }
}

h2,
.h2 {
  font-size: 2.6rem;
  line-height: 3.0rem;

  @media #{$medium-up} {
    font-size: 2.8rem;
    line-height: 3.2rem;
  }
}

h3,
.h3 {
  font-size: 2.0rem;
  line-height: 2.4rem;

  @media #{$medium-up} {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    line-height: 2.2rem;
  }
}

h4,
.h4 {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 2.2rem;

  @media #{$medium-up} {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    line-height: 1.8rem;
  }
}

h5,
.h5 {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 2.0rem;

  @media #{$medium-up} {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    line-height: 1.6rem;
  }
}

h6,
.h6 {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1.6rem;

  @media #{$medium-up} {
    font-size: 1.0rem;
    line-height: 1.4rem;
  }
}

p,
.p {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: $baseline;

  @media #{$medium-up} {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    line-height: 1.8rem;
  }
}

.masthead {
  width: $baseline*20; // 420px
  background-color: $gray;
  height: 100%;
  color: $white;
  float: left;
  padding: $baseline*3 $baseline*4;
  line-height: normal;
}

main {
  background: url('build/img/city-hall.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: $baseline*20; // This is the same distance as the width of the sidebar
}
```

Even through Codepen, this issue remains. Anyone have any clue here? Or should I just not worry about it since its only a dev release? My concern is that this might carry over to later releases, or, considering there is a flicker before the error occurs, I'm wondering if there is something simple I can use to fix this problem.

Finally, here is screenshot of what is happening in both Canary (left) and Chrome Stable (right) side-by-side: http://cl.ly/YFLu

Comment: try using numerical values for `font-weight`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @RandomUser. Unfortunately, this did not fix the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug introduced while simplifying the Mac font back-end. This question is referenced in crbug.com/435822 , and the issue itself was fixed with [crbug.com/421412](http://crbug.com/421412) . I do not believe that this bug made it into a stable release (this time).

The issue was that '-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased' was being ignored. For those who don't know, this is a Mac specific property which is used not to turn on and off subpixel rendering (as one would expect from the name), but to control the fake-bolding which CoreGraphics applies to subpixel anti-aliased glyphs. At larger sizes this fake-bolding is quite noticeable, so it is desirable to disable it on any non-body text. For more details one can read a thread on the www-style list "Text anti-aliasing on the Mac", particularly [this post](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Oct/0109.html). The discussion there came about due to the last time this broke and made it to stable in Chrome 22.

Should this ever happen again (Mac only text seems too bold), one should open a Chromium bug and mention that '-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased' seems to be on the fritz again.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome (almost) always has font problems in Beta. Enter `chrome://flags` in the address bar and enable `disable directwrite`, restart the browser, Everything should look fine now.

BTW in my experience, these font problems are always fixed in the next stable release, most probably FB will also look.. Bolder.[image]

Comment: Hmm. So, either I'm crazy or the directwrite flag has been removed from chrome? I don't see it in the standard Chrome release, either.

Comment: @idealbrandon Sorry, I forgot to mention this is a windows only setting. Are you on windows? If so It should be the fourth option

Comment: Ahh. Nope, my main production machine is Mac OS. I'll test this later and see if this fixes my problem.

Comment: Regardless, from what you are telling me, I really shouldn't worry about this until this rendering bug makes its way into actual release (or at least beta?) channels, correct? If so, then I will just leave it alone. I've seen this issue on so many sites, and have been trying to figure out what is the common thread between them, with no luck

Comment: Honestly, fb.com appears to render fine in both browsers.

Comment: one more piece of random information ... My development setup is a Retina Macbook Pro connected to three external, standard DPI displays. I realized that the page renders correctly on my retina display, but incorrectly on my external displays. Testing the above codepen link on my non-retina iMac with no external displays renders the same bug we have been discussing. Does that lend anymore information that could lead us to an actual cause of this bug?

Comment: It's the media queries! try removing them then checking

Comment: Updated my codepen with no luck =( ... I might just wait on this and see if the issue is fixed during later dev releases. I notice this issue on some sites, but not others. I can't seem to figure out what the common denominator is, though.

Comment: @idealbrandon if it's also on other sites, then I was right, it **is** the canary problem

Comment: Awesome. If thats the case, then I'll close this question out, Thanks for your help!